# jQuery - Editing a newly created div with jEditable not working

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I'm trying to create a frontend editor and I'm getting the data into a new div using an AJAX call, like this:

```
function renderForm(type, position) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'renderForm.php',
        data: "type="+type+"&position="+position,
        success: function(data){
            var editbutoff = $(editbut).offset();
            $(document.createElement('div')).attr('id', 'editor')
                .height(($(divpar).height()+20))
                .width(($(divpar).width()+20))
                .css({position: 'absolute', left: editbutoff.left-($(divpar).width()+20), top: editbutoff.top-20, margin: "5px"})
                .append(data)
                .fadeIn("slow")
                .prependTo(pptest);
        }
    });
}
```

Everything works great 'till here. The new div shows with the data in place and everything looks like it should, but then, a problem arises!

I'm trying to use the jEditable plugin to edit the newly created data, but as the newly created div wasn't there when the document loaded, I made a `.live` event, like this:

```
$("#editor").live('mouseenter', function(){
    $('.edt').editable(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
    $('.edtta').editable(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    }, {
        type: 'textarea'
    });
});
```

Now, the problem is the following:

When I click on the `.edt` element the plugin fires up, creates a new `input` and displays the original text in it, but as the `.edt` element is new, when I try to post the jEditable data it shows up as `<h1 class="edt">` in the console. `<h1 class="edt">` is ofcourse the parent of the input field that jEditable created.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to get the data that I actually entered in the jEditable input field?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i not misunderstand your question, you are trying to get the inputed data prior submission? If so, use the onsubmit method:

```
      $('.edt').editable('@Url.Action('Edit', 'Home')', 
      {
        onsubmit: function (settings, data) {
            var input = $(data).find('input');
            var original = input.val();

            alert(original);
        }
      }
```

You need to use the .find() to get the input then only can get the value by .val()
Hope this help :)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. I asumed the value would be the same prior to submission, so I didn't bother writing any other test. That's what I get for not getting to know the plugins in-depth. :)